# Socket.io data loss when Internet speed drop

Tags: socket.io

I am using socket.io 1.4 and I want to know that what happens in this scenario:
The client  Emits like this:

```
Socket.emit('test',data);
```

The client does 3 emits to server but suddenly Internet speed drops and those emits may not get to server
But after a while the Internet speed rises again but what will happen to previous failed emits? 
They will be emitted again automatically?
How should I handle that

Answer (score 0):

Websockets use TCP, which is in general a reliable protocol.  There is not exactly such a thing as "The internet speed dropped and I lost some messages."  If some messages are lost they will be automatically retransmitted at the TCP level.  If retransmission fails completely, the connection will be reset.

So what you really are asking is how socket.io handles this.  And the answer is that it has some amount of reconnecting logic, and you may also want to monitor the connection in case it resets (hook up a listener for the `disconnect` event on the socket), if you want to take some extra action (like notify the user).